# How can I access command prompt history with Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-console

**On Windows 10, Python 3.6**

Let's say I have a command prompt session open **(not Python command prompt or Python interactive session)** and I've been setting up an environment with a lot of configurations or something of that nature. Is there any way for me to access the history of commands I used in that session with a python module for example?

Ideally, I would like to be able to export this history to a file so I can reuse it in the future.

**Example:**

Type in command prompt: `python savecmd.py`
and it saves the history from that session.

Comment: Windows or *nix? You put cmd, so i'm assuming Windows?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not referring to the interactive Python command prompt or Python interpreter

Comment: @JonathanPorter If you're on *Nix, you can do `history = open('/home/.bash_history').readlines()` and you'd get everything from there. Thing is, I'm not sure how you'll limit it to the current session.

Comment: Similar question for those who want to take editing history from Python further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518255/print-bash-history-using-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Python at all, use `doskey` facilities for that, i.e.:

```
doskey /history
```

will print out the current session's command history, you can then redirect that to a file if you want to save it:

```
doskey /history > saved_commands.txt
```

If you really want to do it from within Python, you can use `subprocess.check_output()` to capture the command history and then save it to a file:

```
import subprocess

cmd_history = subprocess.check_output(["doskey", "/history"])
with open("saved_commands.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(cmd_history)
```

Comment: You could do this in Python via ctypes without doskey.exe, and better even since you could use Unicode instead of the console codepage (which may be a lossy encoding of what you typed if it's not a character in the current codepage). However, it's not supported since Microsoft has never documented the console functions that doskey.exe calls for this: `GetConsoleCommandHistoryLengthW` and `GetConsoleCommandHistoryW`.

Comment: Seem that it's been removed from ctypes. I use: `for i in list(range(readline.get_current_history_length())): print(readline.get_history_item(i))`.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking for 3 different things there.

1. Getting Python REPL command hisotry
2. Getting info from "prompt", which I assume is the Powershell or CMD.exe.
3. Save the history list to a file.

To get the history from inside your REPL, use:

```py
for i in list(range(readline.get_current_history_length())): print(readline.get_history_item(i))
```

Unfortunately, there is no history in REPL, when using from outside, as above, so you need to find the history file and print it.

To see the history file from powershell:

```
function see_my_py_history{ cat C:\<path-to>\saved_commands.txt }

Set-Alias -Name seehist -Value see_my_py_history
```

Comment: My understanding is that `readline` is not for Windows.  I believe that the question is in a Windows context.

Comment: @user2153235 No, there is [pyreadline3](https://github.com/pyreadline3/pyreadline3) for python on windows. However, there were a number of legacy [issues and PR's](https://github.com/pyreadline3/pyreadline3/issues/5) that were never fixed/merged in that, so I'm using the fork from [here](https://github.com/eabase/pyreadline3), which (AFAIK), also was not merged/fixed in pyreadline3.

Comment: I'm just getting to know Python and Conda, so I don't feel savvy enough to deviate from `conda install pyreadline3`. So far, the file from `pyreadline.BaseReadline.write_history_file` has a size of 0 bytes (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76566358/write-history-filepyhistory-str-object-has-no-attribute-mode#comment134997894_76566474)).

Comment: Much troubleshooting later: After importing `pyreadline3` and assigning `readline = pyreadline3.BaseReadline()`, I found that `readline.get_current_history_length()` returns 0 while `readline.get_history_length()` returns 100. From `help(readline)`, this means that no commands are being stored in the history, but there is room to store 100 commands.

Comment: I've posted my trials and tribulations as their own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570300/conda-on-windows-10-python-commands-not-stored-in-command-history)

Comment: @user2153235 `Conda` was created back in the days when Python package management was very unstable and with sketchy platform/compile support. I strongly suggest to move away from *Conda* for any future and regular development. There are also better package management tools now compatible with `pip` such as `poetry` etc.

Comment: Point taken, but I don't feel that option is realistic for me at the moment.  I am a newbie and need to align with how things are done not only in my team and organization, but also with the much more senior person that I am hoping to support, once I become somewhat functionally capable (which should have been last year). Having said that, I'm unsure of how central Conda is to the question of a command history file.  Granted, most IDEs will probably have a way of providing the user with a history, e.g., Spyder, as distributed in Anaconda, so maybe the root issue is using Python without an IDE.