# Print bash history using python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have to print bash history using subprocess package.

```
import subprocess
co = subprocess.Popen(['history'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
History = co.stdout.read()  
print("----------History----------" + "\n" + History)
```

but they prompt an error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    co = subprocess.Popen(['history'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: add `shell=True` in the Popen call [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935151/popen-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popen error: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935151/popen-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: You also want to avoid raw `Popen` as recommended in its documentation.  See perhaps further https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would need to add `shell=True` argument to your `Popen` call:

```
co = subprocess.Popen(['history'], shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or to manually specify the shell you want to call.

```
co = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'history'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Unfortunately, in this particular case it won't help, because `bash` has empty history when used non-interactively.

A working solution would be to read `${HOME}/.bash_history` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Kit is correct, reading `~/.bash_history` may be a better option:

```
from os.path import join, expanduser

with open(join(expanduser('~'), '.bash_history'), 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```